# Shortened Generator Matrix

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

goodmorning, could someone tell me if the following code has been handled correctly?

I have this generator matrix (which I should modify in order to have it correct):
$$G=\begin {bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&0&1&1&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I added line2 and line3 and I replaced line3 with this result

$$G'=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

my main question, however, is this: 
I've been asked to protect from errors the source code of four words (same probability). For this I have to use a shortened code of $\mathcal C(8,3)$. I then should encode those words with the code I obtained.

Four possible words with equal probabilities could be $\{00, 01, 10, 11\}$, right?
Then I started with reducing the $G'$ matrix getting a $G"= (n-1, k-1)$ and deleted the last row and last column.

got

$$G''=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I then encoded the 4 words and got:
$$00 = 000000\\
01 = 010111\\
10 = 100101\\
11 = 110010$$

Now, since I can't check if what I did is correct or not, could someone tell me if I did something wrong and point me out to that?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

EDIT

I think that the shortening of the matrix could be done more correctly by removing a column and a row in a better way. 
What if I remove the last column of the identity matrix and the first row in order to keep the length of redundancy the same?
$$G''=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: From $G$ to $G'$, assuming you're working with a binary code (something you didn't specify), it is correct. The matrix $G'$ is called [*systematic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_code). The rest of what was asked of you and what you did, I've never seen before and I don't understand it. What do you mean with *symbols*? Do you mean *words*?

Comment: yes, sorry, thanks for pointing at it. It's a binary code. Also, yes, symbols = words. Again, something lost in translation. Thanks, gonna edit my post.

Comment: I really don't know because when I studied coding theory I, fortunately, didn't deal with probability. But I'm guessing that saying that the probability is the same just means that you take four $3$-bit words (if they don't have $3$-bits, I don't see how to make sense of this problem), say, $a_1a_2a_3, b_1b_2b_3, c_1c_2c_3, d_1d_2d_3$ and you code them the usual way. Again: I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm guessing too since this is a test-exercise that I will probably find on my exam but can't find similar exercises around. Anyway, I just guessed the 2-bits words because, after shortening the code (from C(7,3) to C(6,2)) I will deal with such kind of word lenght instead of 3-bits.